# PHP file - MySql Failing to Update consistently Resource #3 Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, but I'm not sure why it is only updating about 75% of the files. It gives me a `Resource#3` error.

Can someone please help me understand why I'm seeing this?

FYI - the results include items with spaces.  As an example of the `newsku` field
3265_QZ 132
3266_CE44
3267_405

Thank you in advance for any help,

Here is my code:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT products_id,CONCAT(products_id,'_',products_bin) as newsku FROM products");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$link_id=$row['products_id'];
$products_sku=$row['newsku'];
echo " ***-- updated products_model to : " . $products_sku . "<br>";
$skuUpdate="UPDATE products SET products_model=$products_sku WHERE products_id=$link_id";
$skuUp=mysql_query($skuUpdate,$link);
if($skuUp){
    echo "success..<br>";
} else {
    echo "update failed.  Alert : " . $link . "<br>";
}

}
```

Comment: You should refrain from using MySQL, as it is deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO to keep on top of securing your database from hacking.

Comment: For one thing, try changing this `products_id=$link_id"` to `products_id='$link_id'"`

Comment: Plus this `$skuUp=mysql_query($skuUpdate,$link);` should probably be `$skuUp=mysql_query($skuUpdate,$link_id);` because I don't see how `$link` is defined.

Comment: RUJordan - thank you, you're right, I will begin using MySQLi - thank you! --- Fred, I feel so dumb, that was it.  Thanks!

Comment: @beuki and what about `$skuUp=mysql_query($skuUpdate,$link_id);` or is `$skuUp=mysql_query($skuUpdate,$link);` correct? Because as I stated, I don't see where `$link` is defined.

Comment: @beuki Consider accepting Daniel's answer, to rep him up at the same time. That way he can comment instead at later times. I don't need the added rep points, I'm in this to find solutions. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As Fred -ii- stated in the comment, change:

`products_id=$link_id"` to `products_id='$link_id'"`

`products_model=$products_sku` to`products_model='$products_sku'`

It might help in case you have alphanumeric fields instead of numeric ones. Also check the `$link`, you may not have that variable and you should use another one (`$link_id`)

*PS: I would have commented in the question, but I don't have enough reputation to do it. I'm sorry.*

Comment: No problemo. As long as the OP has an answer that works. Let's rep him up here, shall we? ;-)